# Calendar Not return correct .weekday swift 3.1

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to get weekday of given Date Object. But it always returns +1 value.
example : If I gave a date as : 2017-06-01 18:30:00 +0000

it returns weekday 6 -> Friday
It should bee weekday 5 -> Thursday

My code :

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
        let day: Int = calendar.component(.weekday, from: self.month!)
        print ("---------")
        print(self.month!)
        print (day)
        switch day {
        case 1:print("Sunday")
        case 2:print("Monday")
        case 3:print("Tuesday")
        case 4:print("Wednesday")
        case 5:print("Thursday")
        case 6:print("Friday")
        case 7:print("Saturday")
        default:
            break
        }
```

Output on the Console : (I have given 2 dates both of them ar wrong)

```
---------
2016-01-01 18:30:00 +0000
7
Saturday
---------
2017-06-01 18:30:00 +0000
6
Friday
```

Where I did the mistake...
Thank you.

Comment: what is the locale set for the calendar?

Comment: I did not set any locale for the calendar object

Comment: **There is no problem.** `2017-06-01 18:30:00 +0000` is the GMT/UTC time, that is `2017-06-02 00:00:00` in your timezone, and that was a Friday.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view create extension to the `Date` it is more clear to use:

```
extension Date {
    func weekday() -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: self).weekday
    }
}

print(Date().weekday()!)
```

Example:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-06-01 18:30:00 +0000")

print(date?.weekday()!) //5 In Ukraine
```

Comment: In my iPhone it stil says 6 I have to subtract  1 from the .weekday

Comment: What is timezone and zone of the device that you are using ?

Comment: Colombo UTC+05:30

Comment: @gamal I edit answer try now pls. Try to set calendar dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

Comment: @gamal so your local time is 18:30 + 5:30 = 24:00 = 00:00 + one day. It is correct, isn't it?